# What's the most effective way to create demo accounts with .net Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-identity

I'd like each role on my MVC web application to have a demo account so that prospective SAAS customers can 'give the application a spin'.

I've read SO articles for other architectures, but the approaches aren't suitable or they don't apply to .net.

The accounts will have seed data and allow CRUD that should not affect other users trying out the same demo account or be persisted in the DB.

I imagine having a demo-version of each role, but then each controller/ helper would require specific code for each of those.  Multiple roles for the demo account is a possibility I know, but doesn't help to the extent I'm hoping.

Any tips on how to effectively set up demo accounts with 'Identity.net' ?

thanks